# Why does this code catch block not execute?

Tags: c++, multithreading, error-handling, try-catch

The catch handler is not run. But why?

If the `thread t` is started before the `try` block, the catch handler runs.

If the catch block's type does not match the type thrown, the program exits explaining that the thread terminated with an uncaught exception, suggesting that the exception is handled, yet the catch block isn't run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void do_work() {}

int main() {
  std::cerr << "RUNNING" << std::endl;
  try {
    thread t(do_work);
    std::cerr << "THROWING" << std::endl;
    throw logic_error("something went wrong");
  } catch (logic_error e) {
    std::cerr << "GOTCHA" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compile command:

```
c++ -std=c++14 -pthread -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 scratch.cpp -o scratch
```

Comment: please indent your code before hitting the submit button

Comment: Why on earth does this have a downvote? \*scratches head\*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Someone probably downvoted back when the code had broken formatting.

Comment: @user2079303: Wish they'd keep an eye on the question for more than a few minutes, rather than drive-by downvoting then buggering off!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hear! hear!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to join the thread :

```
try {
  thread t(do_work);
  t.join();                                    // <<< add this
  std::cerr << "THROWING" << std::endl;
  throw logic_error("something went wrong");
} catch (logic_error e) {
  std::cerr << "GOTCHA" << std::endl;
}
```

A [joinable thread that goes out of scope, causes `terminate` to be called](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread). So, you need to call either [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) or [`detach`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) before it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

In **C++11, 30.3.1.3, thread destructor** the standard says

> If joinable() then terminate(), otherwise no eﬀects. [Note: Either implicitly detaching or joining a joinable() thread in its destructor could result in diﬃcult to debug correctness (for detach) or performance (for join) bugs encountered only when an exception is raised. Thus the programmer must ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable. —end note]

Thus your program `terminate`s once the thread destructor is called because the scope ends and the `catch` logic is never executed.

If you want your program to catch the exception out of the thread's scope but throw while the thread is still joinable, you'll need to catch it in the scope of the thread itself, [join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) or [detach](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach) the thread and rethrow whatever has been catched.

```
try 
{
  std::thread t(foo);
  try
  {
    std::cerr << "THROWING" << std::endl;
    throw std::logic_error("something went wrong");
  }
  catch (...) // catch everything
  {
    t.join(); // join thread
    throw; // rethrow
  }
  t.join();
}
catch (std::logic_error & e) 
{
  std::cerr << "GOTCHA: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```